# Unable to push the files to the Git

Tags: git, azure-devops, push

I am using Azure Repos for GIT repo. I have added a gitignore file for VSTS. I created two branches master and develop. I am able to clone the repo during the course of adding the files to staging. Git status does not shows the files to be staged. 
I did ls -a and went inside the .git directory and checked options. everything looked good, I did tried to delete the ignore file and still the problem resisted. I did tried to reinitilase the repo but no luck. 
Error says " working directory clean, nothing to commit"

please help me with it.

Comment: Can you break it down a bit more clearly? It sounds like you are having issues with your ```.gitignore``` that is preventing you from pushing to your remote repository. Sounds like the issue you are experiencing may stem from your ```.gitignore```

Comment: I did tried to remove the .gitignore file. problem remained the same. I have tried to create a repo without the .gitignore file, I had the same problem.

Comment: So, you have stuff that needs to be committed and pushed to your remote branch but Git says you don't have anything. Have you tried checking the other branch?

Comment: Your branch is up to date with 'origin/Develop'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

that's the error

Comment: Try ```cd ..``` to leave your project directory and ```cd <proj_dir>``` back into it and reinitialize your git.

Comment: I have already tried that one too. it doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push the local develop branch to the remote repository, you can do it in two ways. The first one: you switch to the develop branch locally, make some commits in this branch, and then add these commits to the staging area, then synchronize to the local repository, use the `git push origin develop` command to push the contents of the local repository and the develop branch to the remote repository; the second way is to directly push the develop branch to the remote repository using the `git push origin develop` command. If you use the first method but don't do any commits in the develop branch, then `nothing to commit, working directory clean` error will occur when you commit to the local repository.

In addition, if you want to push the commit on the develop branch to the remote repository, you need to use the `git checkout develop` command to switch to the develop branch, and then use `git push origin develop`command to push the commits to the remote repository.

error-causing operations:commit to the local repository without making changes in the working directory

[image]

correct push operations:

[image]